# Dealing with reserved register bits of an ARM chip

Tags: c, arm, cpu-registers

I am working with the registers of an ARM Cortex M3. In the documentation, some of the bits may be "reserved". It is unclear to me how I should deal with these reserved bits when writing on the registers.

Are these reserved bits even writeable? Should I be cautious to not touch them? Will something bad happen if I touch them?

Comment: What chip are you using exactly? Cortex-M3 is only the core, because you are (probably) asking this because of peripheral registers.

Comment: @DipSwitch: Well for example I am talking about the GPIO registers.

Comment: GPIO registers of an NXP, Freescale, Atmel? An STM or perhaps an LPC?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a classic embedded world problem as to what to do with reserved bits! First, you should **NOT** write randomly into it lest your code becomes un-portable. What happens when the architecture assigns a new meaning to the reserved bits in future? Your code will break. So the best mantra when dealing with registers having reserved bits is `Read-Modify-Write`. i.e read the register contents, **modify only the bits you want** and then write back the value so that reserved bits are untouched ( untouched, does not mean we dont write into them, but in the sense, that we wrote that which was there before )

For example, say there is a register in which only the LSBit has meaning and all others are reserved. I would do this

```
ldr r0,=memoryAddress
ldr r1,[r0]
orr r1,r1,#1
str r1,[r0]
```

Comment: This is not atomic. Another process (or interrupt driven by the hardware that uses these reserved bits) might alter a reserved bit in that register between your load and store, and you will overwrite that change, the so called "lost update" problem. So you must either do it in atomic context (OS preemption and interrupts disabled) or you use an atomic compare and swap instruction. Or you get the kind of problems simultaneous access to PC temp sensors from BIOS and OS causes.

Comment: @Z.T. You are right about atomicity here. I put that code just for illustrating the `read-modify-write` concept. Feel free to edit it!

Comment: @Z.T.: Are some hardware designers unaware of what software can or cannot do?  I've seen some parts with registers include both "write 1 to clear" flags and multiple state settings. If the register only included state settings, one could use the bit-band feature to update one state setting without affecting others. If it only included the flags, one could write "1" to the flags one wanted to clear and "0" to everything else. But with the two combined, there's no clean way to update either.

Answer (score 2):

If there is no other clue in the documentation, write a zero.  You cannot avoid writing to a few reserved bits spread around in a 32-bit register.

Comment: We cannot write a 0 out of choice even if the documentation doesn't mention anything. Kindly see my answer.

Comment: @PavanManjunath, I think Martin's point where where you cannot determine what to write. For example some registers are not-readable but they are writable, or some registers have indeterminate read states. In those cases the read-modify-write pattern falls over. Here you would have to write '1's to the fields you want and '0's everywhere else and hope the computer doesn't try to do anything dumb with your '0's.

Answer (score 2):

Read-Modify-Write should work most of the time, *however* there are cases where reserved bits are undefined on read but must be written with a specific value. See [this post](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/lpc2000/message/54079) from the LPC2000 group (the whole thread is quite interesting too). So, always check the docs carefully, and also any errata that's available. When in doubt or docs are unclear, don't hesitate to write to the manufacturer.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you should read-modify-write, no guarantee for success, when you change to a newer chip with different bits, you are changing your code anyway.  I have seen vendors where writing zeros to the reserved bits failed when they revved the chip and the code had to be touched.  So there are no guarantees.  The biggest clue is if in the vendors code you see a register or set that are clearly read-modify-write or clearly just a write.  This could be different developers writing different sections of the example or there is a register in that peripheral that is sensitive, has an undocumented bit, and needs the read-modify-write.

On the chips that I work on I make sure that undocumented (to the customer), but not unused bits are marked in some way to stand out from other unused bits.  We normally mark unused/reserved bits as zero, and these other bits get a name, and a must write this value marking.  Not all vendors do this.

The bottom line is there is no guarantee, assume all documentation and example programs have bugs and you have to hack your way through to figure out what is right and what is wrong.  No matter what path you take (read-modify-write, write zeros, etc) you will be wrong from time to time and have to re-do the code to match a hardware change.  I strongly suggest that if a vendor has a chip id of some sort, that your software reads that ID and if it is an id that you have not tested your code against, declare a failure and not program that part.  In production testing long before a customer sees the product, the part change will get detected and software will be involved in understanding the reason for the part change, the resolution being the alternate part is not compatible and rejected or the software changes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Reserved most of the time mean that they aren't used in this chip, but they might be used on feature devices (other product line). (Most chip manufacturers produce one peripheral driver and they use it for all there chips. This way it's mostly copy past work and there is less change for errors) Most of the time it doesn't matter if you write to reserved bits in peripheral registers, this because there isn't any logic attached to it.

It is possible that if you write something to it, it won't be stored and next time you attempt to read the register / bits it seams unchanged.